# How many Amiga 590 units were sold?

Tags: history, amiga, commodore, hard-disk, amiga-500

The A590 was an external hard disk for the Amiga 500, in 'sidecar' form factor, that could also hold an extra megabyte of RAM.

How many 590s were sold, throughout its life?

Comment: A590 supports up to 2MB RAM.

Comment: I remember it had an average seek time of 80ms highest I saw for a hard drive!

Comment: @nsandersen most Western Digital hard drives of that era were around 80ms. But they weren't the slowest. http://www.alyon.org/InfosTechniques/informatique/drives/other/drivelist.html

Comment: @nsandersen the 80 ms seek time was for the included 20 MB *XT* IDE HD. The A590 also supported SCSI, so all the hip kids (plus me) put a 52 or 80 MB Quantum in it. They were pretty fast